# LIKE clause in CYPHER Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

It appears that LIKE is not supported in Cypher queries.

Is there any other construct that would perform the same task?

For instance:

```
start n = node(*) where n.Name LIKE('%SUBSTRING%') return n.Name, n;
```

Comment: The refcard is a really handy thing to bookmark: http://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/ It lists all supported string matching operators for example.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

using regular expressions:
http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-where-regex

```
start n = node(*) where n.Name =~ '.*SUBSTRING.*' return n.Name, n;
```

Comment: I was worried regex's may be the answer. Groans ;) Still, it makes it more powerful than a simple LIKE

Comment: yes, i'm also concern about regexp but it is the direct way now. but you can still use an lucene index like this : `start n=node:your_index('property:*SUBSTRING*') return n.name, n;`

Comment: and please use parameters instead of literal values: `start n = node(*) where n.Name =~ {like} return n.Name, n;` params: {"like":".*SUBSTRING.*"}, also node(*) as start clause hints at a non-graph use-case, then rather use ulkas' index lookup suggestion

Comment: Seems that it's not working with ".*SUBSTRING.*" but only with "^.*SUBSTRING.*$"

Comment: @MichaelHunger So in an SDN repository having the .* in the argument instead of in the query, forces us to concatenate them in the service layer if we can't fit them in   @Query("MATCH (m:Neo4JManufacturer) where LOWER(m.name) =~ LOWER('{searchTerm}') RETURN m ORDER BY m.name")
  public List<Neo4JManufacturer> search(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm); Is that a correct assumption ?

Comment: I was hoping to do a   @Query("MATCH (m:Neo4JManufacturer) where LOWER(m.name) =~ LOWER('.*{searchTerm}.*') RETURN m ORDER BY m.name")
  public List<Neo4JManufacturer> search(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm);
 but it gives me: Illegal repetition near index 1 .*{searchterm}.*

Comment: I got it working with a repository like LOWER(m.name) =~ LOWER({searchTerm}) and a service with searchTerm = ".*" + searchTerm + ".*";

Answer (score 29):

As of version 2.0, the preferred syntax uses `MATCH`.

e.g.

```
MATCH (n) where n.Name =~ '.*SUBSTRING.*' return n.Name, n;
```

Answer (score 28):

No Regexps needed:

```
start n = node(*) where n.Name contains "substring" return n.Name, n;
```

Go to [the cypher refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) and scroll down to the Predicates section. You will find this and other useful stuff.

Want case-insensitive? Convert to lower case:

```
start n = node(*) where lower(n.Name) contains lower("substring") return n.Name, n;
```

Comment: sadly, it's case sensitive and there's no case insensitive version.  ugh!

Comment: yes, that will work, as will `=~ '(?i)substring'` but it doesn't perform well.  the lower() prevents index usage so on big data it will just hang.  I have an open feature request here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/9450

Comment: The function lower() is no longer supported. Please use toLower() instead.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to make it case insensitive

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i).*SUBSTRING.*' RETURN n;
```