# neo4j search nodes, relationships contains *string*

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Code from [LIKE clause in CYPHER Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828953/like-clause-in-cypher-query)

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i).*SUBSTRING.*' RETURN n;
```

results in

***Expected 1 to be a java.lang.String, but it was a java.lang.Long*** (cause of =~)

Is there a way to for strings case insensitive in all possible places?

Comment: for relationships `match n-[r]-() where type(r)=~ '(?i).* SUBSTRING.*' return distinct type(r)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If

```
MATCH (n) WHERE str(n.name) =~ '(?i).*SUBSTRING.*' RETURN n;
```

works then you've got a node with a `name` property that isn't a String, and that's why the error